# What is the name of the font used in this logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image: JT ROSE & Co. LOGO]

What is the name of the font used in this logo? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi user35967, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Answer (score 1):

By the power of [Identifont!](http://www.identifont.com/list?17+id+9+7TR+2+42W+2+797+2+6EQ+2+2IKD+2+7U3+2+5C7+2+3I6+2+59F+2+40C+3+80Q+3+MA+3+7U8+3+43R+3+2R+3+5AG+3+7WV+3+1ZW+4+214+4+6DM+4+D8L+4+D8M+4+D8K+4+45F+4+TQ+4+7OO+4+4HM+4+4VU+5+TC+5+6C5+6) it looks like [Delphian:](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/delphian/regular?SiteId=15)

[image]

Comment: OMG, you are awesome. Thank you so much. The website are super helpful.

Comment: You're welcome; if that answers your question be sure to click on the check mark to accept it

Answer (score 0):

There is an online font detector to help you out. I would suggest you upload that picture of the logo to [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/) and it will give you the closest match of which font it is.

Here is what were the results:

[image]

So it's either **Caesar Regular** or **Dolphian**

Comment: Based on that typeface 'Dolphian' I'd be wary of that particular site. It looks like its database included a lot of questionable knock-off faces.

Comment: Go to this site and check,the results of that site are accurate: (http://www.dafont.com/dolphian.font)

Comment: To be clear, I'm saying Dolphian looks like a rip-off of Delphian.

Comment: Dafont obviously have no quality control whatsoever. Or they would have noticed that the typeface they published under the name Dolphian was not only a blatant imitation of my Delphian.